# When deploying a Next.js application on Heroku, only the server-side data is obtained, but there is no page rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, next.js, heroku-postgres

if my expression is too verbose or unclear, please let me know and I will immediately make corrections. Thank you.

I encountered some issues while deploying my project to Heroku (as stated in the title). Let me explain the content and configuration of my project.

```
Project/ - Root directory of the project
├── client/ - Client-side code, built with React and Next.js, running on port 3000
│ ├── .env
│ ├── .gitignore
│ ├── package.json
│ ├── package-lock.json
│ ├── next.config.js
│ ├── pages/
│ ├── public/
│ ├── styles/
│ └── ...
--- In order to deploy to Heroku, I moved all server-related files to the project root directory ---
├── config/
├── models/
├── node_modules/
├── routes/
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── server.js - JS file connecting to the server, running locally on port 8080
└── validation.js
```

The main theme of the project is an e-commerce website, which includes user registration and login, CRUD operations for seller's products, a shopping cart system for buyers, and an order system. The database used is MongoDB, and it has been properly configured in MongoDB Atlas. I can successfully send requests via Postman using the Heroku URL.

Currently, when I run the website on the client-side using localhost:3000, all functionalities work fine. However, when I use the Heroku URL, only the requests pointed to by the routes are shown.

For example, when I access the homepage, it should display the UI designed in Next.js along with the data obtained from the server. When running normally on localhost:3000, the following screen is displayed:

```
------------------------------------------
|               Header                    |
------------------------------------------
|       |    |   P   |  |   P   | |   P   |
|   N   |    |   R   |  |   R   | |   R   |    
|   A   |    |   O   |  |   O   | |   O   |      
|   V   |    |   D   |  |   D   | |   D   |     
|       |    |   U   |  |   U   | |   U   |
|       |    |   C   |  |   C   | |   C   |
|       |    |   T   |  |   T   | |   T   |
```

The product information is retrieved from the server.js file by making a GET request to the database.

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let foundProduct = await Product.find({}).exec();
    return res.send(foundProduct);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).send("error");
  }
});
```

However, after deploying to Heroku and accessing the website at https://{my-heroku-url}.herokuapp.com/, the page appears with a black background and white text, displaying the following:

```
[{"_id":"649d4a166b1559bb06d2e832","photo":"data:image/jpeg;base64Q==","name":"test","description":"test","price":4,"sellerName":"test","sellerID":"649d4a036b1559bb06d2e82b","buyer":[],"soldCount":[],"date":"2023-06-29T13:37:28.421Z","__v":0}]
```

It seems that the connection is not being established with the client-side, and only the server-side data is being displayed.

Here are the modifications I made to some files for the deployment on Heroku:

server.js

```
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connecting to mongodb..");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
  
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
  if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ||
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "staging"
) {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html")); 
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("port 8080..");
});
```

project/package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  },
    "engines": {
    "node": "18.9.1"
  }
```

client/package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start -p $PORT", 
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build", 
  "lint": "next lint"
},
 "engines": { 
  "node": "18.9.1"
}
```

heroku Application Logs

```
Application Logs
2023-06-30T04:28:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-06-30T04:28:40.535522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-06-30T04:28:41.851448+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-30T04:28:41.851483+00:00 app[web.1]: > server@1.0.0 start
2023-06-30T04:28:41.851483+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2023-06-30T04:28:41.851483+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-30T04:28:42.247225+00:00 app[web.1]: port 8080..
2023-06-30T04:28:42.709040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-06-30T04:28:44.113115+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to mongodb..
2023-06-30T04:28:45.444562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host={my heroku url}.herokuapp.com request_id=7899e62f-110d-4035-9312-85b83f3f6b78 fwd="219.71.101.29" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1694ms status=200 bytes=168259 protocol=https
```

npm run build

```
> clie
nt@0.1.0 build
> next build

- info Loaded env from /Users/x1/Desktop/Project/client/.env
- info Linting and checking validity of types  
- info Creating an optimized production build  
- info Compiled successfully
- info Collecting page data  
- info Generating static pages (11/11)
- info Finalizing page optimization  

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                      2.55 kB         118 kB
├   └ css/bba6307137d03f3b.css             1.64 kB
├   /_app                                  0 B             116 kB
├ ○ /404                                   182 B           116 kB
├ ○ /seller                                282 B           121 kB
├ ○ /seller/create                         286 B           121 kB
├ ○ /seller/edit/[id]                      280 B           121 kB
├ ○ /seller/order                          285 B           121 kB
├ ○ /user/cart                             313 B           119 kB
├ ○ /user/login                            1.38 kB         117 kB
├ ○ /user/order                            282 B           119 kB
├ ○ /user/profile                          637 B           117 kB
├   └ css/90902db563362695.css             244 B
└ ○ /user/register                         1.38 kB         117 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              117 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-cda2f1305c3d9424.js   45.2 kB
  ├ chunks/main-a9a5f9df1dceef89.js        27.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-363a716366e2f4fa.js  42.3 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack-8fa1640cc84ba8fe.js     750 B
  └ css/b5b71ddc5beffb87.css               1.17 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

The "/404" route is supposed to refer to the index.js file, but currently, it is working fine on localhost:3000. Later, I tested a new Next.js project with all default values and deployed it on Heroku. Everything displayed correctly. It seems that the issue is specific to my project.

Additionally, I have updated all routes that require server-side requests on the client-side to use the Heroku URL. On localhost:3000, my website functions properly. However, when running on Heroku, authorized routes display a white text on a black background (Unauthorized). Routes with data display a black text on a white background (data).

For routes without data, such as "/login," a "Not Found" message is shown with a white background and black text. In the Heroku Application Logs, the following error appears: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'." It seems that the issue may be related to the build and index.html files.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions from the experts to help resolve this issue. Thank you.

Additionally, I noticed that the "/build" directory is included in the .gitignore file of the client folder. Initially, I thought that this might be causing the issue, so I removed the "/build" directory. However, this resulted in the deletion of numerous files from the node_modules directory, causing Heroku to display an error. Even after adding back "/build" to the .gitignore file, the deleted files from node_modules couldn't be recovered.

In the end, I had to use Git to revert to a previous commit in order to recover the deleted files.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
if (
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ||
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "staging"
) {
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```